# Comment in vimrc

Tags: vim

I commented a part of a line using double quotes in my vimrc file, but that part of the line is not commented as can be seen at the bottom of the screenshot below:

[image]

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vim's docs say the following:

> It is not possible to add a comment to a shell command ":!cmd" or to the
> ":map" command and a few others, because they see the '"'' as part of their
> argument.  This is mentioned where the command is explained.

Just put your comments on preceding lines.

[vim's docs are here, for example.](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:comment)

Answer (score 1):

Please, read `:h :comment` in the embedded help system. To quote the most relevant part:

> It is not possible to add a comment to a shell command ":!cmd" or to the
> ":map" command and a few others (mainly commands that expect expressions)
> that see the '"' as part of their argument:

> ...A long list follows...

So just don't.